# Android Studio: How to pause while waiting for AudioRecord to initialize?

Tags: java, android, initialization, audiorecord

I have a simple audio recording app that displays a stopwatch while recording. It starts when I hit the "Start Recording" button and stops when I hit the "Stop Recording" button. However, the amount of time displayed on the stopwatch is not the same as the amount of recorded time. This appears to be due to the initialization time of the AudioRecord class. I'd like to know if anyone knows of a way to delay recording while the class initializes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before start recording audioRecord.startRecording():

```
 while (audioRecord.state != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED);
```

Look at this sample:

```
class RxRecorder(sampleRate: Int, audioFormat: Int, private val bufferSize: Int) {
    var audioRecord: AudioRecord = AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT,
        sampleRate,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
        audioFormat,
        bufferSize)

    fun record() = Flowable.create<ShortArray>({ s ->
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO)
        val audioBuffer = ShortArray(bufferSize / 2)

        while (audioRecord.state != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED);

        audioRecord.startRecording()

        Timber.d("Start recording")
        while (!s.isCancelled) {
            val numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.size)

            if (numberOfShort > 0)
                s.onNext(audioBuffer.subArray(startIndex = 0, count = numberOfShort))
        }

        audioRecord.stop()
        audioRecord.release()
        s.onComplete()

    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)!!
}
```